# Replace Special Characters In Batch-File Variable Feeding ffmpeg program

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I am attempting to write a batch-file that leverages `ffmpeg.exe` to convert all files in a folder structure to mp3 format (specifically 128 KBps).

My batch-file is presently unable to process filenames (constructed by concatenating the `%_SOURCE%` and `%%~F` variables) containing certain special characters generating the following errors:

*No such file or directory*

- `…` ellipsis sign
- `–` en dash
- `—` em dash
- `−` minus sign

*Invalid argument*

- `‘` and `’` curved single quotation marks
- `“` and `”` curved double quotation marks

*Invalid argument* (yet sometimes passes depending on where symbol is in the filename, for example, seems to work if placed between the `n` and `t` of `Dont` in `C:\Users\Test\Documents\Input\Peter Bjorn And John - I Know You Dont Love Me.mp3`)

- `-` hyphen
- `!` exclamation mark
- `~` tilde
- `'` non-curved single quotation mark
- `=` equals sign
- `+` plus sign
- `%` percentage sign
- `(` open bracket

**How can I modify my batch-file script so that the `%%~F` variable escapes these characters correctly?**

Example current filename input: `C:\Users\Test\Documents\Input\Peter Bjorn And John - I Know You Don't Love Me.mp3`

Example desired filename input: `C:\Users\Test\Documents\Input\Peter Bjorn And John - I Know You Don"^'"t Love Me.mp3`

Script (see line beginning **`C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe`**):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=C:\Users\Test\Documents\Input" & rem // (absolute source path)
set "_TARGET=C:\Users\Test\Documents\Output"  & rem // (absolute target path)
set "_PATTERN=*.*" & rem // (pure file pattern for input files)
set "_FILEEXT=.mp3"   & rem // (pure file extension of output files)

pushd "%_TARGET%" || exit /B 1
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    cd /D "%_SOURCE%" ^&^& ^(rem/ list but do not copy: ^
        ^& xcopy /L /S /Y /I ".\%_PATTERN%" "%_TARGET%" ^
        ^| find ".\" ^& rem/ remove summary line;
    ^)
') do (
    2> nul mkdir "%%~dpF."

    rem // Set up the correct `ffmpeg` command line here:
    set "FFREPORT=file=C\:\\Users\\Test\\Documents\\Output\\ffreport-%%~F.log:level=32"
    "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -report -n -i "%_SOURCE%\%%~F" -vn -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "%%~dpnF%_FILEEXT%"
    if not errorlevel 1  if exist "%%~dpnF%_FILEEXT%" del /f /q "%_SOURCE%\%%~F"

)
popd

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: You have a syntax issue with `2> nul mkdir "%%~dpF.` with `.` being suspect. The `FFREPORT` variable value loses single quotes as you do not escape single quotes with backslashs. Unsure why you desire to replace `'` with `"^'"` in the filename.

Comment: Hi michael_heath, thanks for calling out the syntax issue, I have fixed this and it does not resolve the problem..

I have also updated the problem description above to be more explicit about the error messages caused handling of special characters. Hopefully this helps you understand my desire to escape (or replace) certain characters in `%%~F`. I am open to other solutions too.

Comment: A problem appears at the `xcopy` piping to `find`. I have tested with the ellipsis in the filename. At a CMD prompt, type `dir /b` and view the ellipsis. Now type `dir /b|find "."` and view the altered character, which is a period, instead of the ellipsis. The issue in your code seems to be in the `for` command. After the `do` you get the altered value in `%%F` that the system cannot find when processed by ffmpeg. Another solution is to rename the files so the script can process them, as I did long ago with my mp3 collection to avoid any future issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants:
set "_SOURCE=C:\Users\Test\Documents\Input" & rem // (absolute source path)
set "_TARGET=C:\Users\Test\Documents\Output"  & rem // (absolute target path)
set "_PATTERN=*.*" & rem // (pure file pattern for input files)
set "_FILEEXT=.mp3"   & rem // (pure file extension of output files)

pushd "%_TARGET%" || exit /B 1

for /r "%_SOURCE%" %%F in ("%_PATTERN%") do (
    set "_fullpath=%%~F"
    set "_filename=%%~nF"
    call :ffmpeg
)

popd

endlocal
pause
exit /b


:ffmpeg
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Get target path and log path:
for %%A in ("!_fullpath:%_SOURCE%=.!") do (
    set "_logpath=%%~dpAffreport-!_filename!.log"
    set "_targetpath=%%~dpA"
)

for %%A in (_logpath _targetpath) do if not defined %%A (
    echo  ERROR: %%A not defined.
    exit /b 1
)

rem // Escape logpath:
set "_logpath=!_logpath:\=\\!"
set "_logpath=!_logpath::=\:!"
set "_logpath=!_logpath:'=\'!"
set "_logpath=!_logpath:%%=%%%%!"

rem // Set FFREPORT:
set "FFREPORT=file=!_logpath!:level=32"

rem // Make dir for the target file:
if not exist "!_targetpath!" md "!_targetpath!"

rem // Run ffmpeg command:
"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -report -n -i "!_fullpath!" -vn -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k "!_targetpath!\!_filename!%_FILEEXT%"
if not errorlevel 1 if exist "!_targetpath!\!_filename!%_FILEEXT%" del /f /q "!_fullpath!"

exit /b 0
```

Use of `for /f` with a command tends to alter filenames if
contains Extended ASCII such as the ellipsis.

Using a `for /r` to iterate the files gives better results
and have adjusted the code to handle the change.

Added the label `:ffmpeg` to make it easier for working with
the delayed expansion variables etc.

Added `_logpath` variable to store the log filepath with any
backslash, colon or single quote to be escaped with a backslash.
Percent signs are escaped by doubling up.

Added `_targetpath` variable to store the path to where `ffmpeg`
is to output the file. Used by `md` command to make a directory
structure like that of the input.

This may not solve all issues. Tried to do without delayed
expansion though always had some failures depending on special
characters i.e. `%`.

Comment: Hi michael_heath, the solution you proposed does not iterate through all sub-folders of the source directory. This is functionality I need and that was included in the original script. Are you able to tweak your code to enable this?

Comment: Tweaked it for recursion. Using `for /r` to iterate. Since more substring handling was needed, I put much of the code into a label to avoid complex variable expansion requirements.

Comment: Fantastic michael_heath, the script works very well. Thank you so much for all your help.

Just a heads up, you accidentially left an "echo" command in the second last line of the script.